# Pegar info do Banco de Dados a partir do elemento do array

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, pdo

Estou fazendo um carrinho em php. O que eu quero é conseguir pegar o nome do produto (que está no Banco de Dados) a partir do id dele, que é o valor de cada posição do array. Entretanto, como há múltiplos "produtos" no vetor carrinho como faço para criar um loop para buscar no banco o produto a partir de cada posição do vetor?

Vetor:

```
      $_SESSION['carrinho'][] = $_GET['produtoid'];
```

Código de busca no BD a partir do id que está armazenado em cada posição do vetor:

```
       for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['carrinho']); $i++){

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM produto where id = $_SESSION['carrinho'][$i] ";

        $resultado = $PDO->query($consulta); 

        $vetorResultado = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach ($vetorResultado as $valor) {

            echo $valor['nome'];

        }


    }
```

Porém quando executo aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto\carrinho.php on line 24
```

Comment: O erro deve estar na query, adicione chaves por volta do session. Assim: "SELECT * FROM produto WHERE id = {$_SESSION['carrinho'][$i]} ";

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é uma sujestão horrivel porém é o que eu penso que pode dar certo, 
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM produto where id = $_SESSION['carrinho'][$i] ";
isso troque por

$carrinho = $_SESSION['carrinho'][$i];
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM produto where id = '$carinho'" ;

ou

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM produto where id = '$_SESSION['carrinho'][$i]' ";

isso para que o php saiba que  ali é algo em php e não apenas uma string.